# Summing recursive function to itself in Inclusion Exclusion Principle

Tags: java, recursion

This code is for Inclusion-Exclusion Principle to get numbers that are divisible by `2, 3, 5, 7` and it works fine.

```
public class Inclusion_Exclusion_Recursion {

private static int inc_exc(int index , int set , int sign){
    int no_of_elements = 100;
    int[] primes = new int[]{2,3,5,7};

    if(index == 4){
        if(set == 1){
            return 0;
        }
        return sign * no_of_elements / set;
    }

    return inc_exc(index+1, set, sign) +
            inc_exc(index+1, set * primes[index], sign * -1);

 };

 public static void main(String args[]){
    System.out.print(inc_exc(0, 1, -1));
 }
}
```

I understand Recursion as a technique but i don't understand how the recursion works, when we sum the recursive function to itself.
    `inc_exc(index+1, set, sign) + inc_exc(index+1, set * primes[index], sign * -1);`

When i investigated i find that the first recursion `inc_exc(index+1, set, sign)` decreases the index each time, the index reach to `4` (I don't understand this point too). Then the second recursion start working `inc_exc(index+1, set * primes[index], sign * -1)`, correct me if i'm wrong.

**Could you explain in detail, how this recursion works ?**

Comment: Please read about java naming conventions. You solely use the "_" for SOME_CONSTANT. Class names go UpperCamelCase, and variables go camelCase, and method names should go "doWhatever" (include a verb that is).

Comment: Work through it on paper.

Answer (score 0):

Your recursion stops, if the index reaches 4. If index is not 4, result of the method call is the sum of two recursion calls:

```
return inc_exc(index+1, set, sign) +
        inc_exc(index+1, set * primes[index], sign * -1);
```

Now you have two function calls in your call stack with index 1. This is still not 4 and you continue with 2 * 2 = 4 recursion calls with index 2. In the end you have 2 ^ 4 = 16 function calls with index 4 (because you start with index 0 in your main function).

Answer (score 0):

```
* Here we traverse the binary tree of divisors for simplicity {5,3,2}
* ----------------------------------
*  5             3           2
* -----------------------------------
 * 0
 *               0
 * 1
 *                           0
 * 0
 *               1
 *
 * 1
 *
 *
 * 0
 *               0
 * 1
 *                           1
 * 0
 *               1
 *
 * 1
 * ----------------------------------
```

1 means that it is a devisor of n .
0 means that it is a devisor of n.
Every call represent that we go form one bit to the adjacent one
if it is 1 we multiply the old product with the current divisor.
Also note that the parity of no. of 1s changes so we change the sign.
At the last bit of every path in the tree we calc the total numbers that are divisible and return it to be summed with others.